# error: reached end of file while parsing in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is my 1st time using Java and Android, I’m trying to  launch a simple application with `WebView` script.

Everything was okay but I am facing issue  when I’m trying to add loading bar for my web view page. The problem:

```
error: reached end of file while parsing
```

I’m using this code for `Mainactivity`

```
package com.example.last;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;
    private ProgressBar mProgressbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView =(WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

        mProgressbar=findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mProgressbar.setMax(100);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://beko963.000webhostapp.com");

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
                mProgressbar.setProgress(newProgress);
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
                super.onReceivedTitle(view, title);
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedIcon(WebView view, Bitmap icon) {
                super.onReceivedIcon(view, icon);
            }
        }}

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed () {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }}
```

And using this for main XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/WebView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I just want to make a simple application with loading icon, could you please help my and fix my code?

Comment: `webView.setWebViewClient(new WebChromeClient() {` where is the closing `)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Correct your code

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
                mProgressbar.setProgress(newProgress);
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
                super.onReceivedTitle(view, title);
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedIcon(WebView view, Bitmap icon) {
                super.onReceivedIcon(view, icon);
            }
        })
```

Comment: Thank you , but I received this error 
setWebViewClient
(android.webkit.WebViewClient)
in WebView cannot be applied
to
(anonymous android.webkit.WebChromeClient

Comment: I have modified my answer please change setWebViewClient to setWebChromeClient.

Answer (score 0):

As [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/857132/john3136) and Others Says

`webView.setWebViewClient(new WebChromeClient() {}}` where is the closing `)`

```
//replace last } with );
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
                mProgressbar.setProgress(newProgress);
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
                super.onReceivedTitle(view, title);
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedIcon(WebView view, Bitmap icon) {
                super.onReceivedIcon(view, icon);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you , but I received this error 
setWebViewClient
(android.webkit.WebViewClient)
in WebView cannot be applied
to
(anonymous android.webkit.WebChromeClient